Indexation error on google console : Page is not indexed: Duplicate without user-selected canonical
I have a report from Google search console that gives me:
https://catalogue.cappiello.fr/etiquette-produit/escalier/?product_count=24
to be a duplicated to
https://catalogue.cappiello.fr/etiquette-produit/escalier/
without canonical URL.
It is not the only error, I got it on several urls :
https://catalogue.cappiello.fr/etiquette-produit/cuillere/?product_view=list https://catalogue.cappiello.fr/etiquette-produit/trompette/?product_orderby=default&product_view=grid
When editing my tag, I can put a canonical url with Yoast SEO plugin, but I think it doesn't make sense to say : for the tag "escalier", the url is https://catalogue.cappiello.fr/etiquette-produit/escalier/ and the canonical is : https://catalogue.cappiello.fr/etiquette-produit/escalier/, does it ?
How should I fix this google warning ?

"Duplicate without user-selected canonical" is a warning, not an error.
It tells you that Google have chosen which page should be canonical, and decided that one is not canonical.
Warnings are for information, and not all of them need action. If Google had indexed the wrong URL, then you would need to do something to let Google know which is the right one to index.  It does not sound like that is the case here.
There is nothing wrong with the URL and canonical tag being the same, in fact it is normal.  It means that there's a clean version of the URL that cannot be broken by external links adding URL parameters to it.
It is good practise to use canonical links on these things for the sake of getting the details right, but Google usually guess right.
I'd perhaps look at why that URL is in Google's index in the first place - you are usually just wasting crawl budget by allowing them to crawl your filter pages.
